# How to integrate a package updates in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, updates, scripts, repository

I have made a .deb file which I have hosted on an Apache server. What I want is that the software should get updated automatically along with other software & Ubuntu updates as shown in the image. How can I do that?

See the image below for clarification on what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You then want to setup an APT repository:

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

http://www.hadrons.org/~guillem/debian/mini-dak/

If you don't want to maintain the infrastructure yourself, you can register an account on launchpad and create your own PPA. It should be free as long as the project is open source.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

After the repository is created, you have to add it to your APT sources:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: I have already created the repository. Does that mean the update will take place automatically?

Comment: I have done all the above. I used reprepro for building my repository. What I am asking is will the future updates to my software will automatically reflect in my client software.